# MomentJS ISO date formatting

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Date before ISO conversion it was like 'Sat Oct 22 2016 00:18:38 GMT+0530 (IST)' But after convert using moment i.e. moment().toISOString() It gives

result output like '2016-10-21T18:48:00.337Z', here it gives date 21.

why?

Comment: Can you show your code please

Comment: @brianlmerritt sure, Actually that problem exist on the server side when I send this time. In client side , I used this let date = moment().toDate() , so suppose its give output like 'Sat Oct 22 2016 00:18:38 GMT+0530 (IST)' and on server side I've used this date to convert into ISO format  like date.toISOString(). It give result like '2016-10-21T18:48:00.337Z'

Comment: That looks like just the timezone difference? ISO format is UTC (+0:00) by definition. Or am I reading this question completely wrong?